# What server to take?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I had problems with full-text search using Amazon RDS (SQL Server 2012). It is slow for some reason.

I saw there are other kind of preset servers on EC2 which feature a SQL Server and Server 2012 in a bundle on same server.

If I take that bundle, do I get access to filesystem for SQL Server 2012? Reason I ask that is SQL Server 2012 on RDS does not provide me with file system access.

Does it behave like normal server where I can remote to machine and use SQL Server Management Studio?

I asked this question on Amazon forum first, but I am not getting answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> If I take that bundle, do I get access to filesystem for SQL Server 2012?

Yes.

> Does it behave like normal server where I can remote to machine and use SQL Server Management Studio?

And yes again.

However, it would be a better off first trying to figure out *why* your RDS instance is slow.  Make sure you're using a large enough instance size, enough diskspace (full-text indexes consume a very large amount of diskspace), and make sure you're using [provisioned IOPS](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/09/new-high-performance-provisioned-iops-amazon-rds.html).  I've utilized full-text indexes on SQL Server on RDS and it was unusable without provisioned IOPS.  Use CloudWatch metrics to take a look at your disk queue length.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd say is check the quality of your database. Are you using indexes efficiently? Are you using slow queries? What performance metrics are you currently using?

The primary differences between RDS and EC2 is the level of access and specialism:

- With RDS, you only have access to your data - i.e. you cannot SSH in and reconfigure the OS
- With EC2, you have your own space - i.e. you can SSH in and reconfigure the filesystem and any subsequent EBS volumes you attach. The root drive of an EC2 is generally set to 8Gb, meaning that any large data set (in your SQL database) will need to reside on a mount - meaning that you will have to reconfigure the DB config setup.

Have you looked into [Amazon CloudSearch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/)?

Answer (score 0):

If you create an EC2 instance with a SQL Server installation you will have full acces including windows login.